# Typeahead автокомплит с сохранением кода

Tags: bootstrap

В доке по bootstrap есть пример с автокомплитом:
http://bootstrap-ru.com/203/javascript.php#typeahead
А нет ли примера, как сделать чтобы при выборе элемента в поле выводить имя, а где-то (например в хидден поле) сохранять код выбранного элемента и далее использовать его?

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто, нужно инициализировать `typeahead` со своей функцией `updater`:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  // ...
  // ваш код инициализации
  // ...
  updater: function(item) {
    $('#hiddenInput').val(item);
  }
});
```

[Пример](http://jsbin.com/eVESAqU/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Спасибо.
Также подскадите а могу ли я в массиве данных задать и текст выбора и его кода, вроде:
    source_array={ "32":"Item 1","31":"Item 2" } 

Я так попрообовал и автокомплит перестал работать.

А чтобы получить код по его имени единственный вариант это аджаком лезть в базу и выбирать код оттуда ?